# Wordpress not showing custom 404 page for not found images, zip files

Tags: 404-error

My blog all the web page not found errors shows the theme's 404.php file. But if someone click on the file link (.img, .zip), it doesn't show that themes not found page. Instead of that it shows web browser "The webpage cannot be found" error page. For an instance http://www.example.com/sample.img (if this page doesn't exist it shows web browser 404 page, not the theme page)

Logged in user can see this error (if click on invalid zip or img file) "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option() in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/splash/404.php on line 1".

I use hotlink protection htaccess code.

Is it a htaccess issue or 404 page issue? Are there any way to correct it?

Comment: I just tested this and I do get the theme 404 page. Please explain what you've done in more detail.

Comment: Thank you s_ha_dum! I have a stranded installation. WP default 404.shtml available on the default location. I have added this htaccess code to redirect the 404 errors. ErrorDocument 404 /wp-content/themes/splash/404.php That's what I have done. Any help appreciate!

Comment: That’s completely wrong. Never set direct links to themes files in a .htaccess. Let WordPress handle it for you, and it will work.

Comment: toscho! If I remove that line, Wordpress will redirect all the 404 pages to my theme 404 page? I read most of the custom redirection tutorial, mentioned that, htaccess redirection requires to use a custom 404 page. Is it wrong?